# Multisteps form creation with relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to implement a multistep form following this article: https://medium.com/@nicolasblanco/developing-a-wizard-or-multi-steps-forms-in-rails-d2f3b7c692ce

The problem is that my model has relationships and these are not recognized in the step 3 presenting an error, see below my full code and the error message:

```
class Evaluation < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :teacher
    belongs_to :school
    belongs_to :subject

    has_many :evaluation_tags
    has_many :tags, through: :evaluation_tags

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :evaluation_tags

    validates :teacher_id, presence: true
    validates :subject_id, presence: true
    validates :school_id, presence: true
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :rating, presence: true
end


module Wizard
  module Evaluation
    STEPS = %w(step1 step2 step3).freeze

    class Base
      include ActiveModel::Model
      attr_accessor :evaluation

      delegate *::Evaluation.attribute_names.map { |attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: :evaluation

      def initialize(evaluation_attributes)
        @evaluation = ::Evaluation.new(evaluation_attributes)
      end
    end

    class Step1 < Base
      validates :teacher_id, presence: true
    end

    class Step2 < Step1
      validates :subject_id, presence: true
    end

    class Step3 < Step2
      validates :school, presence: true
      validates :user, presence: true
      validates :rating, presence: true
    end
  end
end


class EvaluationsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :complete_sign_up, except: [:index]

    # before_action :load_evaluation_wizard, except: %i(validate_step)
    before_action :load_evaluation_wizard, except: [:validate_step, :new]

    def step1
        @teachers = Teacher.includes(:schools).where(schools: {id: current_user.student_details.last.school_id}).order(full_name: :ASC)
    end

    def step2
        @teacher_id = session[:evaluation_attributes]["teacher_id"]
        @subjects = Subject.includes(:teachers, :schools).where(teachers: {id: @teacher_id}).where(schools: {id: current_user.student_details.last.school_id}).order(name: :ASC)
    end

    def step3
        pp session[:evaluation_attributes]
    end


    def validate_step
        current_step = params[:current_step]

        @evaluation_wizard = wizard_evaluation_for_step(current_step)
        @evaluation_wizard.evaluation.attributes = evaluation_wizard_params
        session[:evaluation_attributes] = @evaluation_wizard.evaluation.attributes

        # pp session[:evaluation_attributes]

        if @evaluation_wizard.valid?
            next_step = wizard_evaluation_next_step(current_step)
            create and return unless next_step

            redirect_to action: next_step
        else
            render current_step
        end
    end


    def load_evaluation_wizard
        @evaluation_wizard = wizard_evaluation_for_step(action_name)
    end

    def wizard_evaluation_next_step(step)
        Wizard::Evaluation::STEPS[Wizard::Evaluation::STEPS.index(step) + 1]
    end

    def wizard_evaluation_for_step(step)
        raise InvalidStep unless step.in?(Wizard::Evaluation::STEPS)

        "Wizard::Evaluation::#{step.camelize}".constantize.new(session[:evaluation_attributes])
    end

    def evaluation_wizard_params
        params.require(:evaluation_wizard).permit(:teacher_id, :subject_id, evaluation_tags_attributes: {tag_ids: []}).merge(user: current_user, school: current_user.student_details.last.school)
    end

    class InvalidStep < StandardError; end

end


#STEP3.HTML.ERB

<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name) do |tag| %>
  <%= tag.label(class: "tags tags-bom") { tag.check_box(class: "checkbox_tags") + tag.text} %>
<% end %>


#ERROR

undefined method `tag_ids' for #<Wizard::Evaluation::Step3:0x00007fadb2be6a88>
```

How can i make that module recognizes the relationships?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need a custom validation for `tag_ids`. I don't think rails will validate multiple items in one step. Maybe add a custom validation at the bottom of your application controller:

```
def validate_tag_ids
  if !tag_ids.is_a?
    errors.add(:tag_ids, :invalid)
  end
end
```

And then use:

```
validates: :validate_tag_ids
```

instead of:

```
validates :tag_ids, presence: true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is not in validation